# Issue with video volume with Javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to set the audio for all my video tag elements to a lower value, but the only thing that works is by using `getElementbyId` as far as I have tried. But I tried this code below, and it should work:

Here's the JavaScript code snippet:

```
document.getElementByTagName('video').volume = 0.5;
```

but this does not work.

Comment: Do you have some example code or an example fiddle? Something to look at or play with to test this out.

Comment: You should be able to use something like ($('video').prop("volume", 0.5); (jquery)

Comment: Hello, i have about 7 different video tags, and i tried this code, document.getElementsByTagName('video')[0].volume = 0.5; but it only reduced the volume for the first video, why is that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use below code:

```
var nodes = document.getElementsByTagName('video');
var videos = Array.prototype.slice.call(nodes);
videos.forEach(function(video) {
  video.volume = 0.5;
});
```

It takes all the video nodes from the page, saves them to array, and for each element sets volume to 0.5

Comment: Hey i tried the code the guy below me commented, and it worked, but only for 1 video,

Comment: Hey could you explain this code, and what it all does, ? :) as i've just started learning about javascript, and this is a little messy to understand right now :D